# Find and replace via macro in Sublime Text 2 to switch from mysql_ to mysqli_

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I have a bunch of code that needs transitioned from PHP's `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*`

In Sublime Text 2 I can easily do a find for `mysql_` and replace it with `mysqli_`

The problem I run into is:

`mysql_query($query, $link_identifier)`

versus

`mysqli_query($link, $query)`

To make things worse $query is not always the variable name for the query string.
I may have:

```
$q_test = "SELECT `lName` FROM `users` ORDER BY `lName`";
$rstest = mysql_query($q_test, $DB) or die(mysql_error($DB));
```

and

```
$q_tester = "SELECT `address` FROM `users_address` ORDER BY `id`";
$rstester = mysql_query($q_tester, $DB) or die(mysql_error($DB));
```

on the same page.

Is there a way for me to construct a macro in Sublime Text 2 to change both of the above to:

```
$rstest = mysqli_query($DBi, $q_test) or die(mysqli_error($DBi));
$rstester = mysqli_query($DBi, $q_tester) or die(mysqli_error($DBi));
```

at the same time?  I'm thinking I can use a regex to accomplish this I just have no idea how and where to start.

**UPDATE**

So, after a little hunting I found that I can search for:

```
mysql_query\(\$(\w+), \$DB\)
```

and replace with

```
mysqli_query\(\$DBi\, \$$1)
```

which converts 
`$rstest = mysql_query($q_test, $DB) or die(mysql_error($DB));`

to

`$rstest = mysqli_query($DBi, $q_test) or die(mysql_error($DB));` for me but...

turns out you can't macro Find and Replace.  Do I have any options?

**UPDATE**

So it looks like I can use the plugin [Reg Replace](https://github.com/facelessuser/RegReplace) to accomplish what I want even though I have more setup to do.

Using Reg Replace I can chain multiple find and replace actions together and bind them to a keystroke so I can basically do a series of find and replace actions to get what I need:

1. Find and Replace `mysql_` with `mysqli_`
2. Find and Replace `$DB` with `$DBi`
3. Find and Replace `, $DBi) or die(` with `) or die(`
4. Find and Replace `mysqli_query($` with `mysqli_query($DBi, $`

Those basically get

`$rstest = mysql_query($q_test, $DB) or die(mysql_error($DB));`

converted to

`$rstest = mysqli_query($DBi, $q_test) or die(mysqli_error($DBi));`

for me in a single keystroke.  It's not optimal but it does the trick.  I'm still looking for a simple, no plugin solution however.

UPDATE
The above works with Sublime Text 3 using the [updated Reg Replace plugin](https://github.com/facelessuser/RegReplace/tree/ST3)

Comment: So Sublime 3 can't record find/replace in macros either?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since sublime does not have the ability to record find and replace using a regex in a macro for now I'm going to use [Reg Replace](https://github.com/facelessuser/RegReplace) and a series of chained find and replace commands to get what I'm looking for.